# docker-compose volume mount is empty when using docker toolbox (windows)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerise my laraver 5.5 application using `docker-compose`.

Here's my **docker-compose.yml** file definition:

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=myapp"
      - "MYSQL_USER=myapp"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

  # The Application
  app:
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker-compose/app.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - "DB_CONNECTION=mysql"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_DATABASE=myapp"
      - "DB_USERNAME=myapp"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=123456"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

and this is my **./docker-compose/app.dockerfile**:

```
# Base image
FROM php:7.1-apache

# Configure system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        mysql-client \
        zlib1g-dev \
        --no-install-recommends \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

# Add php.ini and apache2.conf
COPY docker-compose/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker-compose/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

#  Configuring Apache
RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-available/* \
    && rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*

# Enable rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Download and install composer globally
RUN curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Add vendor binaries to PATH
ENV PATH=/var/www/html/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

I use the following command to start up my stack:

`docker-compose -d --build` via the `Docker Quickstart Terminal` on my Windows 10.

Everything builds fine and runs (I checked via `docker-compose ps`). When I visit the app url, I am getting forbidden error from apache, so I decided to login to the container using `docker exec -it my_app_1 /bin/bash` command and I went into `/var/www/html` directory and noticed that it's empty.

Doesn't volume mounting works in windows?

Comment: Try using the full path on your host in the mount without a trailing slash: `- /full/path/to/project:/var/www/html`. I've ran into some oddities with volume mounts and corrected it with full paths. Also, try using just `context: .` under build.

Comment: If it is a path issue, you can use `docker-compose config` to see the effective configuration that compose will use with relative paths expanded to absolute paths.

Comment: @btl I don't want to hard code the path to app, it has to be relative (because the application will be worked on by other devs also under various os/setup). I am using `context` under build.

Comment: @loganrakai I ran the command and this is what I got out: https://pastebin.com/raw/g5bEyw5V  - looks like the context uses the windows path style, where as the volume uses the linux path style? How can I rectify this?

Comment: @Latheesan I use env variables to set paths: `${HOST_DIR}:${CONTAINER_DIR}`. Recently found out about `docker-compose.override.yml`, that's been really handy for allowing other devs to customize their setups, too.

Comment: @Latheesan One thing to try if you haven't already is to set the environment variable COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_convert_windows_paths.  Possibly related issue discussed here https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4303

Comment: @loganrakai I've just tried this and I am seeing no difference.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with empty mount directories. If I mount single files, it gets mounted, but directories are copied to container but empty. Since, the files are copied, I don't think it should be issue with the file path.